# I am having trouble seeing if my hostnames from my file are either an A record or an alias

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, dns

Here is my script and I'm good up to bold section. I'm trying to finish my script by seeing if my hostnames are an A record or an alias. I'm having no luck and really need someones advice. I've tried using grep and awk and seems to not work.

```
#!/bin/sh
#Query DB for cnames
#Pulling cnames
#Lets use sed to clean up and remove "" that regex miss.
#Added dos2unix to get rid of the hidden M from /tmp/final.csv

mssql -f csv -c ~/applications/mssql/mssql.json -q "SELECT * FROM Cname" | cut -f 3 -d "," | sed 's/["]//g' | sort | uniq | dos2unix >/tmp/final.csv  

#Validating cnames from file /tmp/final.csv

while read -r host  
do  
    echo $host | egrep "^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)+([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$" >/dev/null 2>&1  
if [ $? -eq 0 ]  
    then  
        echo "host $host 8.8.8.8"  
    else  
        echo "unable to resolve '$host'" >&2  
fi  
done < /tmp/final.csv

# removed weird stars from some of these lines -- thrig
#Verify whether it's an A record or an alias  
LOOKUP=`host $host 8.8.8.8`  
if [ $? -eq 0 ]  
    then  
        echo $LOOKUP | grep -f "alias" | awk '{print $2}'| grep -v '#' | awk '{print $2}'  
    else     
        echo "$LOOKUP is null"  
fi
# what is this in relation to?? -- thrig  
done
```

Comment: That is where I am having issues. I am trying to see which hostnames from /tmp/final.csv are either an A record or alias. Not sure how to get that to work and I'm sure the code is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alias in DNS is a CNAME, so if you're checking for that, it would be best to query for that record type, use the option '-t CNAME'. Also you might want to consider using dig instead of host (I think host is deprecated, but not sure about that), because it doesn't return anything if it's an A record, and might be easier to test for than how host returns. For example:

```
$ dig -t CNAME +short ftp.med.cornell.edu
web-prd01.med.cornell.edu.

$ dig -t CNAME +short web-prd01.med.cornell.edu
```

That last command has no output. If you really want to use host:

```
$ host -t CNAME ftp.med.cornell.edu
ftp.med.cornell.edu is an alias for web-prd01.med.cornell.edu.

$ host -t CNAME  web-prd01.med.cornell.edu
web-prd01.med.cornell.edu has no CNAME record
```

I think you should be able to finish up the script with that.

Comment: `host` and `nslookup` are indeed deprecrated/not recommended tools for DNS operations. `dig` is the recommended one.

Comment: From where did you get that `host` is deprecated? It comes in the same package from ISC as `dig`. It's just a simpler version of `dig`.

Comment: deprecated is maybe too strong, it is just that once you learn to use `dig` there is no case where you need to go back to `host`. So why learn 2 tools where one is clearly all you need? As the documentation says: "The domain information groper (dig) is the most versatile and complete of these lookup tools." (discussion being between dig, host and nslookup)

Comment: I thought I read it in a man page that host was going to be deprecated but I can't find that anymore. There was a plan to deprecate nslookup and host back in 2004, so maybe that is what I was thinking of:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup